# Make Set prevent duplicated URL

Tags: java, kotlin, url

It's possible to prevent duplicated URL on `Set`?

Like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/somethings
http://www.mywebsite.com/somethings/
```

URL come dynamically, so, I don't know what is the url that will come, it can come with and without bar on final. I need to add all url's on `Set` preventing adding the same URL.
I know that bars on final make the URL different, but it's possible to prevent it on `Set`?

```
private var urlList: MutableSet<URL> = mutableSetOf()
```

or

```
private var urlList: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()
```

It is `Kotlin`, but sample in `Java` are welcome.

Comment: What are your rules? You've shown that the end / should not count. What is www.mywebsite.com different from mywebsite.com? What if two domain names point to the same IP? But de-duping based on IP address also has its issues... Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: what about .../index.html?

Comment: @ControlAltDel in my project all URL come with www and http, the only rule is that it can come with / or without on final, duplicating the result, I can't make it stop with this results, then I need to "filter" it on my project

Comment: If is possible to filter all results (including rules that you mencioned), great! But I only need to prevent with / on final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Alter your input to match.

If no SLASH on the end, append one.

```
if ( ! input.endsWith( "/" ) ) { input = input + "/" ; }
```

## Details

To address your question narrowly…

No, [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) implementations bundled with Java are not savvy about how to compare objects of a specific class. The `Set::add` method merely calls the `equals` method. To quote the Javadoc:

> `boolean add​(E e)`
>
> adds the specified element `e` to this set if the set contains no element `e2` such that [`Objects.equals(e, e2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)).

`Objects.equals(e, e2)` merely calls the `Object::equals` method present on every class. So, next we should examine how the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method on `URL` class works.

First notice in the top of the `URL` Javadoc page, [URL escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is *not* applied when comparing URLs. If two URLs are effectively the same, but one is URL-escaped and the other not, they are *not* considered equal.

Quoting the Javadoc for `URL::equals`:

> `public boolean equals​(Object obj)`
>
> Compares this URL for equality with another object.
>   If the given object is not a URL then this method immediately returns false.
>
> Two URL objects are equal if they have the same protocol, reference equivalent hosts, have the same port number on the host, and the same file and fragment of the file.
>
> Two hosts are considered equivalent if both host names can be resolved into the same IP addresses; else if either host name can't be resolved, the host names must be equal without regard to case; or both host names equal to null.
>
> Since hosts comparison requires name resolution, this operation is a blocking operation.
>
> Note: The defined behavior for equals is known to be inconsistent with virtual hosting in HTTP.

### `URL::equals`

I am not sure what all that means, so let's try it. Actually, we must surround this code with a try-catch for `MalformedURLException`, but we can ignore that here.

```
URL a = new URL( "http://www.mywebsite.com/somethings" );
URL b = new URL( "http://www.mywebsite.com/somethings/" );

boolean isEqual = Objects.equals( a , b );
```

> Objects.equals( a , b ): false

Nope, not equal. The terminal slash on the end means they are not equal.

Just to be sure, let's try a real URL.

```
URL a = new URL( "https://www.apple.com/mac" );
URL b = new URL( "https://www.apple.com/mac/" );

boolean isEqual = Objects.equals( a , b );
```

> Objects.equals( a , b ): false

Add a slash to the first as a sanity-check.

```
URL a = new URL( "https://www.apple.com/mac/" );
URL b = new URL( "https://www.apple.com/mac/" );

boolean isEqual = Objects.equals( a , b );
```

> Objects.equals( a , b ): true

Yes, adding the slash makes the URL objects equal.

### `URL::sameFile`

Let's try the `URL::sameFile` method mentioned in the [Answer by ControlAltDel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861034/642706), in place of `Objects.equals`.

```
URL a = new URL( "https://www.apple.com/mac" );
URL b = new URL( "https://www.apple.com/mac/" );

boolean isEqual = a.sameFile( b );
```

> a.sameFile( b ): false

Nope, that does not serve your purpose either.

### Append `/` if omitted

As a workaround, I suggest that if your only issue is the SLASH at the end, manipulate your input strings before constructing your `URL` objects.

```
String input = "https://www.apple.com/mac";
if ( ! input.endsWith( "/" ) )
{
    input = input + "/";
}
```

> https://www.apple.com/mac/

Comment: you missed `?` and `#`. Also `&` or `%xx`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I mentioned URL encoding. As for [fragment identifiers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and [query strings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), the Question seems to be very specifically asking only about SOLIDUS character on the end.

Comment: In general, you'd need to convert each URL to some canonical representation, that took care of trailing slashes and any other constructions you considered equivalent.  (I don't think there's a standard way to do any of that, because it's up to the web servers concerned as to which URLs they direct to the same page.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's how to do it (maybe)

Because URL is final, you need to create a wrapper class on URL and add objects of the URLWRapper into your set

```
public class URLWrapper {
  private URL url;
  public URLWrapper(URL url) {
    ...
  }
  public URL getURL() {...}
  public int hashCode() {
    return url.hashCode() + 1; //so it doesn't clash with the URL.
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof URLWrapper)) return false;
    return ((URLWRapper)o).getURL().sameFile(this.url);
  }
}
```

You should test sameFile - I don't actually know that this will work in all the cases you are interested in. But if it doesn't, you need to implement a method like sameFile yourself.